# OnsenUI and components.onsenui.io

Tags: onsen-ui

Could someone please clarify me the relationships between OnsenUI AngularJS based directives and the patterns I can find on components.onsenui.io?

I mean, when I find an interesting pattern, should I use plain html or are there corresponding pre-implemented OnsenUI angular directives which "translate" it?

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a member of Onsen UI team.
We have plan to combine the Onsen CSS Components and the Onsen UI.
Currently we concentrate on the release of Onsen UI next version.
If you have any question, please contact us.